# multiple $http calls in angular sp app

Tags: sharepoint-online, angularjs, js

I am trying to chain together some http calls using angular to access the 'current' ProjectUID.  I need to use this in a variable.  I've looked at quite a few articles, and recognized the issue I was running into was due to the nature of making async calls to SP.

I think I am close, but cannot figure out how to chain the calls together effectively using the promise method.  Currently, i don't see anything in the console.  Please advise:

```
//controller for late tasks
app.controller('tasksController', function($scope, $http){
  function getPropertyID(){
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/allProperties?$select=MSPWAPROJUID",
      headers: {"Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"}
    })
  }
function setPropertyID(data){
  var ProjectUID = data.d.MSPWAPROJUID;
  console.log(ProjectUID);
  return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/ProjectData/Projects(guid'" + ProjectUID + "')/Tasks",
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"}
  })
}
$scope.tasks = function(){
  getPropertyID()
  .then(function(data){
    setPropertyID(data).success(function(data){
      var results = data.d.results.length;
      console.log(results);
      return results;

    }).error(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    })
    

  })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, one of the first things I see there, and likely the reason you are not seeing any `console.log` entries, is that you are assigning `$scope.tasks` to be a function, but you are not executing that function.

In Javascript, you can assign a variable to *be* a function.  If you do that, two things do *not* happen:

- the function does not automatically get executed
- even when it does get executed, the return value from that function does not become the new value of the variable, the variable is still the function

For instance:

```
var myThing = function () {
    var something = getTheThing();
    return something;
}
```

All that does is say that `myThing` is a function *waiting to be executed*. It doesn't actually run until you do

```
myThing();
```

And, even after you do that, `myThing` does not suddenly have the value of the returned `something`.  Even after you execute it, `myThing` is still a function, that you could execute again by calling `myThing()` again. In order to get that returned value `something`, you would have to do

```
// you have to execute the function, and then assign
// the return value to another variable
var theRealThing = myThing();
```

So going back to your code example, when you do

```
$scope.tasks = function () {
    // stuff with console.logs in it
    return something;
}
```

it does not execute immediately.  In order to see the `console.log`s, you would have to then do

```
$scope.tasks();
```

If you execute the function like that, you will start to see your `console.log`s, however, remember that the return value from that function does not then become the value of `$scope.tasks`, it will still be the function you defined it as.

My guess is that you do not actually want `$scope.tasks` to be a function, what you want it to be is the tasks from the project.  You are getting close with how you are chaining your functions that make the two async REST calls, you just need a little bit more to handle both responses and pass that data back to where you need it.

[Before we go any further, I'd just like to point out that I have never used Angular, so I am not 100% familiar with `$http` or how Angular scoping works. So I am making some assumptions here, but my code example may not work *exactly* as I am intending because of things I don't know about how Angular works.]

I would suggest using a `Promise` that you create yourself (not the ones automatically created by `$http`) so that you can control exactly when that Promise resolves, so that you can make sure you have all the data together at the time you resolve the Promise.

Also, I would make a few adjustments to the code to make things a little more logical and readable, for instance, your function `setPropertyId` does not actually *set* anything, it uses the project ID you got in the previous function to then get the tasks for that project.  It might be more appropriate to name that function `getTasks`, since that's what it does.  Also, you pass the full response object from `getPropertyID` into that function, and then make that function (`setPropertyID` aka `getTasks`) deal with the response from `getPropertyID`.  It would make more sense for the success handler for `getPropertyID` to deal with the response it receives and peel the ID off it.  Then, if `getTasks` needs a project ID in order for it to work, then *pass only the project ID into it*.  It will make it much more clear as to what that function needs to work and what it actually does.

So here is an example of how I would set up what you are trying to do (again, with the caveat that I don't know Angular, so it's untested and might not work *exactly* as is, but you should see the general idea):

```
//controller for late tasks
app.controller('tasksController', function ($scope, $http) {
    function getPropertyID() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/allProperties?$select=MSPWAPROJUID",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
        })
    }
    function getTasksFromProject(projectId) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/ProjectData/Projects(guid'" + projectId + "')/Tasks",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
        })
    }
    function getProjectIdAndTasks () {
        // return a Promise from this function so that _you_
        // can control when it resolves, since you want this
        // whole process to wait for both the request to get the ID
        // _and_ the request to get the tasks
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            getPropertyID()
            .then(function (projIdResponse) {

                // don't just pass the full response on to the next function,
                // deal with it here and get the data you want from it so
                // it's more clear what data you are getting from where

                var ProjectUID = projIdResponse.d.MSPWAPROJUID;
                console.log('got the project id:', ProjectUID);
                
                // now just pass what the next function actually needs
                // (the project id) on to the next function
                getTasksFromProject(ProjectUID).success(function (tasksResponse) {

                    // the 'length' property of the results array is really just the count,
                    // it's not the actual tasks themselves
                    var numberOfTasks = data.d.results.length;

                    // the actual tasks themselves are in the 'results' array
                    var tasks = data.d.results;

                    console.log('got the tasks:', tasks);
                    
                    // resolve the outer promise with a custom object
                    // that has both the project ID and the tasks
                    resolve({
                        projectId: ProjectUID,
                        projectTasks: tasks
                    });

                }).error(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);

                    // reject the outer promise because there was an error
                    reject(error);
                })
            })
        });
    }
    
    // set off the whole process, and then once you get the result from
    // your resolved promise, you can set that data where you want it
    getProjectIdAndTasks().then(function (bothResults) {
        console.log('got both project ID and tasks:', bothResults);

        // now that you have all the data you want from the server,
        // assign it where you want it

        $scope.tasks = bothResults.projectTasks;
        $scope.projectId = bothResults.projectId;

    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('could not get project ID and tasks:');
        console.log(error);
    })
})
```

For more info on `Promise`s, look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).  And if you are new to Javascript and want to learn more about how it works, I highly recommend the eBook series ["You Don't Know JS"](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/1st-ed).

Comment: thank you! this was really helpful.  i will take a look and reedit.  I really do appreciate all your time and help!

Comment: I think what is holding me up is when I go to pass the ProjectUID variable... I have it logged in the first funciton, but it always returns undefined no matter & I'm unsure why that is.

Comment: In which first function? Did you change to using my example where I have `var ProjectUID = projIdResponse.d.MSPWAPROJUID;` before calling `getTasksFromProject`?  If so, try just logging `projIdResponse` to see what the response is in full, and see if you can figure it out from there.  Also, there is no error handling on `getPropertID()`, you could try adding `getPropertyID().then(function(projIdResposne) { // what's there already }, function(error) { console.log('there was an error:', error} )` to see if `getPropertyID` is throwing an error.

Comment: Figured it out lol. made a typo.  To note, I did have to alter where we call the scope for tasks as it did not print out the variable for some reason.  Thank you very much for your help!  I also added an additional call for the LastModifiedDate!

Comment: And to cmnt on the note, I'm aware that the length is just the number.. I needed that [along with further filtering based on date/time addtl fields] to indicate how many tasks were late.  I don't actually need all the tasks!